# Why does a VirtualBox error completely locks my Ubuntu (lubuntu) desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, ms-dos

I'm using VirtualBox *(Version 5.1.38_Ubuntu r122592)* under lubuntu *(Linux hostname 4.4.0-148-generic #174-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 7 12:20:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)* to start turbo debug under a DOS 6.22 VM.

When I start td.exe VirtualBox hangs and completely locks my desktop.

Here the screenshot:

[image]

**System information:**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
```

**Virtualbox installation information:**

```
virtualbox:
  Installed: 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3
  Candidate: 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? What's the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like an error in VirtualBox. You should follow the instructions provided in the window you have shown in a screenshot.

Comment: @Melebius. I hope someone knows the problem and help me to solve it ... :)

Comment: That’s OK but I’d expect it to be much more probable on http://forums.virtualbox.org/ than here. And you should provide _all_ the information requested in the window.

Answer (score 1):

The most plausible explanation is that `VirtualBox` (froze your Ubuntu because it) used up all the available RAM. Maybe test it while keeping an eye on `top`?